# MVC How to collect additional information based on what's changed in a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm still on the conceptual stage of this problem, so I'm open to suggestions on how to go about solving the problem. The problem is this:

I have a web form. Users are editing data. When they submit the changes, I need to determine which fields are different, and then collect additional information for each field, like, find out why they changed a value.

I'm not allowed to use javascript to handle this task because some users will have javascript disabled.

So, how do I request additional information based on information already submitted, and how do I keep all the information straight so I can submit it all to the database correctly once it is all collected?

I can see submitting the changes, and then in the controller checking against the database (or hidden fields previously given to the view) to figure what fields are different, but then I don't know how to request additional information of the user based on that.

Comment: If you are not going to use javascript for whatever reason you will have to check that in your controller so you are in the wright path. Return your object compare it and display whatever you need in the view based on the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the approach of checking against the database to see which fields have changed (if you use hidden inputs remember that those can be tampered with - if your application is critical you'll want to avoid that).  Once you know that something has changed, I would persist the new user input somewhere (disk, session, database, etc) so that you can access it later to actually persist it in the existing record in the database.

If you need to request additional information, once you've stored what the user submitted just return another view and form for the user to submit back to you.  Depending on what your needs are, if you need to get a description for each field, perhaps just build a collection of fields that have changed and iterate over that collection in the view to ask for input.